# Grails Date unmarshalling

Tags: json, grails, unmarshalling

If I get the following json from a RESTful client, how do I elegantly unmarshal the java.util.Date? (Is it possible without providing (aka. hard-coding) the format, that's what I mean by elegantly...)

```
{
  "class": "url",
  "link": "http://www.empa.ch",
  "rating": 5,
  "lastcrawl" : "2009-06-04 16:53:26.706 CEST",
  "checksum" : "837261836712xxxkfjhds",
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The cleanest way is probably to register a custom DataBinder for possible date formats.

```
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomDateBinder extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private final List<String> formats;

    public CustomDateBinder(List formats) {
        List<String> formatList = new ArrayList<String>(formats.size());
        for (Object format : formats) {
            formatList.add(format.toString()); // Force String values (eg. for GStrings)
        }
        this.formats = Collections.unmodifiableList(formatList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String s) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (s != null)
            for (String format : formats) {
                // Need to create the SimpleDateFormat every time, since it's not thead-safe
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
                try {
                    setValue(df.parse(s));
                    return;
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }
    }
}
```

You'd also need to implement a PropertyEditorRegistrar

```
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar;
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistry;

import grails.util.GrailsConfig;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {
    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry reg) {
        reg.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateBinder(GrailsConfig.get("grails.date.formats", List.class)));
    }
}
```

and create a Spring-bean definition in your grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    "customEditorRegistrar"(CustomEditorRegistrar)
}
```

and finally define the date formats in your grails-app/conf/Config.groovy:

```
grails.date.formats = ["yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZZZ", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"]
```

Comment: Just wondering if there's a reason you would choose to implement this in Java (as above) rather than Groovy? The code would be quite a bit shorter with Groovy.

Comment: I implemented a similar piece of code in Java in former times when Groovy was much slower than it is now. Groovy made a great leap forwand in this matter. I'm just reusing the old Java code out of lazyness ;-)

Comment: Nice piece of code, classic of what you'd do. Though the cleanest way would be to use the Locale to retrieve the format rather than iterate through parsing tries.

Comment: i'm getting the following warning: `project/src/java/CustomEditorRegistrar.java uses or overrides a deprecated API`. is there a 'new' way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

Be aware that the new version of Grails 2.3+ supports this type of feature out of the box.
See [Date Formats for Data Binding](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html)

With that said, if you are forced to use a version of Grails prior to 2.3, the `CustomEditorRegistrar`
can be updated using the following code to eliminate the deprecation warning, and also uses the `@Component` annotation, which allows you to remove / skip the step of adding the bean directly in `resources.groovy`. 
Also not that I changed the grails configuration property name to grails.databinding.dateFormats, which matches the property now supported in Grails 2.3+. Finally, my version is a .groovy, not .java file.

```
import javax.annotation.Resource
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistry
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
public class CustomEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

    @Resource
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry reg){
        def dateFormats = grailsApplication.config.grails.databinding.dateFormats as List
        reg.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateBinder(dateFormats))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. You saved my day. @BindingFormat is the right choice.