# How to pass Date values as params in Grails

Tags: date, grails, groovy, parameters

I have seen a few posts related to using the g:datePicker in Grails.  Using this it looks like you can just pick the value off the params like so params.myDate.

However, when I try to do something like this in my view:

view:

```
<g:link controller="c" action="a" params="[fromDate:(new Date())]">
```

controller:

```
def dateval = params.fromDate as Date
```

The date is not parsing out correctly.  Is there something else I should be doing in the view to make the date 'parsable' by the controller.  I've looked around and haven't found this in any posts where datePicker is not used.

Comment: My plan right now is to just pass the .time portion of the date, but if Grails has some magic I don't know about and can't find, would rather use that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer to send time instead of dates from the client.

```
<g:link controller="c" action="a" params="[fromDate:(new Date().time)]">
```

And in action I use the constructor of Date that takes time.

```
def date = params.date

date = date instanceof Date ? date : new Date(date as Long)
```

I have created a method in DateUtil class to handle this. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

When the parameters are sent to a controller they are sent as strings. The following won't work

```
def dateval = params.fromDate as Date
```

Because you haven't specified what date format to use to convert the string to a date. Replace the above with:

```
def dateval = Date.parse('yyyy/MM/dd', params.fromDate)
```

Obviously if your date is not sent in the format `yyyy/MM/dd` you'll need to change the second parameter. Alternatively, you can make this conversion happen automatically [by registering a custom date editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871977/grails-date-from-params-in-controller/2872291#2872291)

Comment: Do you have your `parse(String, String)` parameters backwards?  [Groovy Date Specification](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @typoknig you're right the params were in the wrong order - I've corrected the error

Answer (score 4):

Whatever is sent from view is a string so `params.fromDate as Date` does not work.

In grails 2.x a date method is added to the params object to allow easy, null-safe parsing of dates, like

```
def dateval = params.date('fromDate', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

or you can pass a list of date formats as well, like

```
def dateval = params.date('fromDate', ['yyyy-MM-dd', 'yyyyMMdd', 'yyMMdd'])
```

or the format can be read from the messages.properties via key `date.myDate.format` and use date method of params as

```
def dateval = params.date('fromDate')
```