# GORM default Date format when sending date to Grails

Tags: json, date, grails, grails-orm

I am sending a JSON PUT request to Grails.  In the JSON object, I have a date string.  I have searched and experimented, but I cannot determine the default date string format that GORM wants to parse the date string.  In all my attempts I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date

I just want to know the default format GORM expects and I will happily format the date string in that format before sending it to the server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suppose you face this issue during data binding.

**Reason:**
Default date format for binding is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`

**Solution:**
The default data format can be changed using [PropertyEditorRegistrar](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/PropertyEditorRegistrar.html). Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243717/2051952) for details.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! Can you tell me where you found this default format documented?  I couldn't find it anywhere.  I could find lots of info about formatting when sending to client from server, but not vice versus.

Comment: @JoshPetitt I was in the same boat few months back but dig through source code to find it out. Worth adding to the docs.