# How to put a Date into params in Grails

Tags: grails, controller, integration-testing

I am working on Controller Test in Grails 2.2.3 and I have a Date field in a Domain.
However when you are testing Controller you suppose to put everything into params and apparently params must have everything in Strings.

How do I put Date into params?

Example of params:

```
    params["issueNumber"] = 1
    params["dateOfIssue"] = "2014-05-16 09:17:38 EDT"
    params["placements"] = [location:"Sample location", page:1, column:1, row:1]
    params["newsPaper"] = [name:"Sample Ad Name"]
```

For "placements" & "newsPaper" - they are param representation of other domains.
Above example fails on `controller.save()` and doesn't output much of useful information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the way params is bound to a command object or domain class, if it is bound at all. Considering a domain class is directly bound in the controller action which has a field named `dateOfIssue`, below is the default date format that has to be used

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S
```

Now this can also be customized globally if you are using Grails 2.3.* by providing config settings for date formats by adding `grails.databinding.dateFormats` as:

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = [
    'MMddyyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"
]
```

Refer [date formats for data binding](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding) docs for details.

For Grails 2.2.3, refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241914/bind-date-to-command-object-in-grails) in order to bind a custom date format. Hope that helps.

Also, keeping aside the whole data binding stuff, if that is not being used at all, then obviously whichever format is standardized for your app below transformation can be used to get a date from String:

```
Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z", "2014-05-16 09:17:38 EDT")
```

Comment: I'll take your solution but I also discovered another one

Answer (score 0):

I discovered another way to pass date via params that might not be as pretty as [dmahapatro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23701024/635610) provided but it doesn't require any modifications. Example:

```
    params["dateOfIssue"] = "Fri May 16 00:00:00 EDT 2014"
    params["dateOfIssue_year"] = "2014"
    params["dateOfIssue_month"] = "5"
    params["dateOfIssue_day"] = "16"
```

Original field name is "dateOfIssue".

Comment: I think a params["dateOfIssue"] = "struct" is missing

Answer (score 0):

You can create a StringToDateValueConverter to accomplish this.

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29552305/568179) (it is also locale aware)