# java.lang.NullPointerException in command object

Tags: grails

I want to parse a string to date just before validate a command object, here is my command object code

```
class ActivitiesCommand {
    List schools
    List departments
    Date from
    Date to

    static constraints = {
        schools nullable:false
        departments nullable:false
        from blank:false
        to blank:false
    }

    def beforeValidate() {
       def from = new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd", from)
       def to = new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd", to)
    }
}
```

but i am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` when i try `def from = new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd", from)` or `def to = new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd", to)`.  What can i do in order to successfully parse the date before validate command object?

I read the command object docs.  I got this sample from there.  I tried if removing **?** beforeValidate does not work, so i understand i need to provide a null safe but i do not know how to do it in my scenario

```
class Person {
    String name

    static constraints = { name size: 5..45 }

    def beforeValidate() { name = name?.trim() } 
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from` and `to` is set to Date in the Command Object, so request parameter string with `from` and `to` names will be converted to a Date and then bound to these field.

If the expected date format matches then binding will be successful.

In your case, `from` and `to` in `beforeValidate` is treated as `String` instead. If they are `String` actually then you can make them `nullable: false` in constraints or do the check as below in `beforeValidate`:

```
from = from ? Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", from) : new Date() - 1 //for example
```

Note the appropriate use of `Date.parse()`

Comment: I am trying @dmahapatro recommendation here is the code  

def beforeValidate() {
from = from ? Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", from) : new Date() - 1
}  

Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'to'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "2014-05-31"

Comment: i also remove beforeValidate and its content, and removed from blank:false, and to blank:false from constraints in order to see if there is some automatic convert from strin to date, no success and same error message  Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'to'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "2014-05-31"

Comment: solution fix original question java.lang.NullPointerException, but i need know to parse string date to Date before validate command object that was the original intention for using a beforevalidte.

Comment: Yes I was about to suggest to look at this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241914/bind-date-to-command-object-in-grails/17243717#17243717 for older version of Grails