# grails datepicker only provides default date to controller

Tags: grails, controller, datepicker, gsp

When I attempt to use the grails datepicker, when I try out the page the value that gets sent to the controller is the default value, not the actual date value that I've chosen in the datepicker fields.

I'm using the grails datepicker in my simple index.gsp page:

`<g:form action="show">
    game ID:  <g:textField name="gameId" value=""/><br/>
    switch date:  <g:datePicker name="switchDate" value="${new Date()}"/><br/>
    <g:submitButton name="submit" value="submit"/>
</g:form>`

my equally simple show controller:

`def show(long gameId, Date switchDate) {
    println("gameId:$gameId  switchDate:$switchDate")
}`

I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with the `Date` not being bound properly.  If you access it through `params.switchDate` or change the parameter to be of type `String`:

```
def show(long gameId, String switchDate) {
```

then it works.

Alternatively you can follow the steps from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871977/binding-a-grails-date-from-params-in-a-controller) to set up proper data binding for the Date, i.e. by setting:

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['MMddyyyy HH:mm:ss']
```

in your `Config.groovy`.