# Send LocalTime object via parameters from gsp in Grails

Tags: grails, jodatime, gsp

I've input time field in my Grails application:

```
<joda:timePicker name="startTimeReservation" value="${new LocalTime()}" precision="minute" />
```

I want to send its value to action in controller via parameters. This is a code from controller where I catch this value:

```
oldCafeeInfo.startTimeLimit = params['startTimeReservation']
```

During parameters are send, I get a such error:

```
Cannot cast object 'struct' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'org.joda.time.LocalTime'
```

How to send parameters correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own alternative. I noticed what `params['startTimeReservation']` comes to controller as a string "struct". Also, in logs, I noticed, what this struct is divide by `startTimeReservation_hour` and `startTimeReservation_minutes`. They contain integer-values, which are parse easy! Then these values may be transfered as parameters to the `new LocalTime(hour, minute)`. So we've created new LocalTime instance which can be recorded to the database. Somehow, I doubt this is a good variant, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

In request all data is String, so you need to parse string:

```
oldCafeeInfo.startTimeLimit = LocalTime.parse(params['startTimeReservation'], format)
```

format is SimpleDateFormat.

Or you can use next answers, for do it automaticaly by binding: [Binding a Grails date from params in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871977/binding-a-grails-date-from-params-in-a-controller)