# Grails Timestamp

Tags: postgresql, grails, intellij-idea

i have i simple CRUD application that stores data to a database.
I try to import date and time from a single input by a bootstrap datepicker. But i got some weird error.

Service

```
def insertAction(String id, String name,String thl,Timestamp dt1){
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.execute("INSERT INTO  mn (id, name, thl, dt1) VALUES (${id as long},$name,${thl as long},$dt1)")
    }
```

Controller

```
 def save() {
        println params
        [customer: customerService.insertAction(params.id,params.name,params.thl,params.dt1)]
        redirect action: "list"
    }
```

GSP

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for ="dt1">Date :</label>
                    <div class='input-group date' id="dt1">

                        <input id="" name="dt1" type='datetime' class="form-control" >

                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#dt1').datetimepicker({

                });
            </script>
```

Postgres column is set to timestamp

I added the following code

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(params.getDate("dt1").getTime())
```

and the erros in now this

```
URI
    /Test/customer/save
Class
    org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException
Message
    No message found under code 'date.dt1.format' for locale 'en_US'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your controller:

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(params.getDate("dt1").getTime())
[customer: customerService.insertAction(params.id,params.name,params.thl,ts)]
```

As by default when you get a variable using `params.key`, value is of String type. You need to manually convert it to desired type.

Comment: and why getTime must be empty?

Comment: params.getDate("dt1") gives you a date object and getTime() will give you a long representation of this time using which we are creating a new timestamp object.

Comment: yes but i still get an error pointing to Timestamp. I edited the post. Take a look if you can

Comment: regarding that error take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2872291/1799527