# Grails LazyMap to POJO Conversion failed due to Date value

Tags: json, grails, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.4 and jersey request builder plug-in.

I am getting below error on

```
def resRequestList = RESPONSE FROM REST REQUEST
ResourceTest item1 = resRequestList.get(0)
```

error is

```
Cannot cast object '{createdBy=2576, endDate=10-Jun-2016, id=14}'
with class 'groovy.json.internal.LazyMap' to class 'com.modal.resource.ResourceTest' 

due to: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '10-Jun-2016' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'
```

It looks like conversion failed from Sting to Date.

I needs solution to map it automatically to POJO without string to date conversation error.

There should be anything which do preprocessing before casting.

Please Help.

Comment: you may want to check this: http://notetodogself.blogspot.sg/2010/12/convert-map-to-object-in-groovy.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find alternate solution which is best fit to me.

I have used reflection to get original List of Object using GenericType.

My Code is as below

```
def resRequestList = clientResponse.getEntity(new GenericType<ArrayList<ResourceTest>>(){});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `@BindingFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy')` annotation to your date field in `ResourceTest` class. You can also use `grails.databinding.dateFormats` config option to set default, global binding format. See this answer for details: [Binding a Grails date from params in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871977/binding-a-grails-date-from-params-in-a-controller).

I would also recommend not to send month as `Jun` as this is locale specific and may not work dependning on your environment.

Comment: Hi droggo. Thanks for reply, My ResourceTest class is POJO not POGO. How do i add @BindingFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy') in POJO class.