# Grails action argument date binding

Tags: grails, data-binding

In controller's action Date argument used

```
def action(Date start, Long id){
   ....
}
```

Data binding by default not works for Date type. During invocation start variable initialized by current time for parameter value '**01/05/2016**'.

Date binding works well for domains with Date start field

```
someDomain.properties = params
bindData(someDomain, params)
```

How to activate it for action arguments?

PS

*grails.databinding.dateFormats* configured well

Grails 2.4.5

**Updated:**

I have seen [Binding a Grails date from params in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871977/binding-a-grails-date-from-params-in-a-controller) , I use provided solution with **ValueConverter** for custom binding, and it works only for domains and commands binding

Comment: Did you try to use command object instead of these two arguments?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc with command object it should work, but it not suitable for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding a Grails date from params in a controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871977/binding-a-grails-date-from-params-in-a-controller)

Comment: @VinayPrajapati no. The question was not about action arguments. Also, I have tested solutions with ValueConverter before writing the question

Answer (score 1):

If you want dates to be bound using the formats configured under `grails.databinding.dateFormats` then you either need to use a command object or call one of the overloaded methods `params.date('start')`.

I don't know why you're so reluctant to use a command object. You've said in a comment that this solution is "not suitable", but I'm curious to know *why* a command object is unsuitable.

Binding dates directly to action arguments is a feature that simply does not exist.

Comment: `Binding dates directly to action arguments is a feature that simply does not exist.` which is interesting, because it is possible in Spring. Maybe something possible in Grails 3.x?

Comment: @Gregg yes. it's possible in spring MVC. And I don't want to produce dummy command object only for date binding

Comment: @Dónal  params.date('start') is require for date format in message properties for every variable name. Try to execute params.date('start') and will get exception

Comment: @demon101 there are overloaded versions of `params.date()` that allow you to supply one or more date formats to use

Comment: @Dónal for date format Grails can use default format from message.properties. And I prefer also use some default format (in the best case with localization support). But construction like params.date('my_date', message(code:'default.date.format')) or  params.date('my_date', MySettings.DATE_FORMAT) looks ugly