# Grails json string converter with Dates

Tags: grails

I'm POSTing json data to a Grails controller which I then parse using JSON.parse.
It all works fine except for date fields. I don't believe there is an explicit syntax in json to represent a Date but I've tried a number of formats with no luck. Can anyone tell me what format I should use so that the grails JSON parser can create a Date object.

Comment: This question has some time, but well here is an answer that I think solves your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963922/grails-date-unmarshalling

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific format, but you can define your own. For example, these guys [here](http://www.nikhilk.net/DateSyntaxForJSON2.aspx) are adding a '@' to the beginning and the end of the string.

According to Grails docs [here](http://grails.org/Converters+Reference), you can define:

> **grails.converters.json.date** (String) - Configure how Date values
>   are serialized to JSON
>
> - "default" - String representation according to the JSON specification
> - "javascript" - new Date(...)

*Update:* It appears that there is no [mapping](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/MappingBetweenJSONAndJavaEntities) to Java Date objects. If you know the fields that are dates, you can [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) them into Dates

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help me. I'm looking to understand how the Grails framework parses JSON to produce Groovy/Java Date Objects. I haven't found any documentation on how this works or how to define my own.

Comment: Thanks.. That info is specifically about how Grails generates JSON rather than parsing incoming JSON. 
I have tried against the ISO_8601 format (EG 2010-07-26T12:36Z) and that still is left as a String instead of a Date.

Comment: @sub It appears that there is no [mapping](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/MappingBetweenJSONAndJavaEntities) to Java Date objects. If you know the fields that are dates, you can [parse](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse) them into Dates.