# display date / save date in Grails

Tags: java, grails, date

Is there any way to save / view date in our prefered format ? like dd/MM/yyyy instead of using simple date format everytime I save the date fields ?

for example:
I would like to have

```
class User {
 Date birthDay ; 
}
```

the user will save the birthDay as '31/12/1988' for example and I would like to display it as that ... without format("dd/MM/yyyy") everytime I found the date (or converting string to date) for saving / updating)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use metaClass to display the date in wanted format.

```
Date.metaClass.toString = {
  -> format('dd/MM/yyyy')
}
```

Comment: You set metaClass for a class. This means set it as  soon as  possible, e.g. in bootstrap.groovy. Another option is to set metaClass for needed instances, e.g. yourDate.metaClass.toString = {...}

Answer (score 2):

look also at the first answer on [Grails Date unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963922/grails-date-unmarshalling)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about date display, you'd better register an [own PropertyEditor](http://omaha-seattle.blogspot.com/2010/02/custom-grails-property-editor.html) - with it,  will use PropertyEditor's formatting.

If it's about saving to database, you'll need to set up a [custom Hibernate type mapping][2].

[2]: http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5. Object Relational Mapping (GORM).html#5.5.2.10%20Custom%20Hibernate%20Types