# java.util.Date unmarshalling form grails json request

Tags: json, grails, unmarshalling

I'm facing following error while trying unmarshal java.util.Date from JSON in grails controller.

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '2011-10-07 10:24:40' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'**

Also, I've tried the following method but still no luck, actually I've doubt wether I've implemented following in right way or not because when i put println statements in  following method:

```
public CustomDateBinder(List formats)
```

Nothing prints on console.

[Grails Date unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963922/grails-date-unmarshalling)

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of your error message you are trying to convert a String to Date, if you want to do it manually you can use the following method  in your Controller (since Grails 2)

```
 def val = params.date('myDate', 'dd-MM-yyyy') //Obviously you need to change the format
```

Check the following post for more info: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/01/grails-goodness-date-request-parameter.html

Comment: This is not the case. I've to unmarshal whole json object into plain groovy class. e.g def clazz = new MyClass(jsonObj)

Comment: Wich version of Grails are you using?