# parsing date in grails from a json file

Tags: json, parsing, date, grails

I'm working with a JSON file, and I need to transform it into an object. Everything seems easy so far, but I found a problem trying to parse dates.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
//My JSON file
data={
    "title":"myTitle"
    "releaseDate":"2012-05-28"
}

//Myclass
class Book{
String title
Date date
}

Book book = JSON.parse(data)
```

And I receive an error:

```
Cannot cast object  with class 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject' to class 'Book' due to: 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '2012-05-28' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'
```

I think I know why is this happening (Obviously, I can't cast a String into a Date) but I've no idea how to fix it.

I've also tried to define in `Config.groovy` my format date, like this:

```
grails.converters.json.date = 'yyyy-MM-dd'
```

Comment: this seems like a duplicate of  [Grails date unmarshalling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963922/grails-date-unmarshalling/964083#964083)

Comment: I already saw this post, but that solution is not working for me. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That is a quite discussed topic recently. Recent GRAILS version, say 3.x, has powerful simple support. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871977/binding-a-grails-date-from-params-in-a-controller). 
Briefly, you have to insert in application.yml or in application.groovy a list of general formats to clarify conversion into Date from String. For example in application.groovy:

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.S'Z'", 'ddMMyyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss']
```

and in this way if you have a domain Book.groovy with a Date property

```
def book = new Book(JSON.parse(stringJson))
```

will work perfectly. Tested with GRAILS 3.1.6.