# How use registerCustomEditors for multiple dates?

Tags: grails, data-binding

Well, here is the code I've tried so far.

```
public class CustomDateEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"), true))
        registry.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new StructuredDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"), true))
    }

}
```

I am using a calendar jQuery plugin and a regular grails DatePicker, if I just use the first one, I always get an error with the regular grails Date Picker. If I use both, I don't get an error anymore.. However, the calendar saves just the date and not the time? Anyway to fix this? :(

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this:

[Grails Date unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963922/grails-date-unmarshalling)

and this

[Binding a Grails date from params in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871977/binding-a-grails-date-from-params-in-a-controller)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can register multiple editors for the same type, so I would instead write my own `MultiDateEditor` subclass of `CustomDateEditor` (or implement `PropertyEditorSupport` directly) which tries to bind a date using multiple formats. Then you only need to register `MultiDateEditor`:

```
public class CustomDateEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new MultiDateEditor(
                ["MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", "MM/dd/yyyy"]))
    }    
}
```